# Any disadvantage to using braces on same line or new line for C#

Tags: c#

I have been using the default of new line for methods and code blocks but it's using up a lot of space. Should I use the curly brace on the same line as the start of the method? Is there any disadvantage to doing this?

Comment: Take cover! A religious war is going to start here!

Comment: whatever makes you feel better and understand code quicker

Comment: If you have a coding style guide, just follow the guide. This is a must if you are working on a team. Otherwise, try the use the most generally accepted style (just from my experience).

Comment: By the way, you can have a look at the [Wikipedia article about indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), it provides supposed pros and cons of the various indent styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disadvantage of putting the opening `{` on the same line: some people don't like it, and some people find it harder to read.

Disadvantage of putting the opening `{` on the next line: some people don't like it, and it takes up more vertical space.

I think next line looks prettier, but I don't really find it easier or harder to read assuming the code is indented nicely.

If you are working in a team with standards mandating one or the other then you should follow the standard, otherwise do whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in my opinion there is. Simply put, readibility. If not for you, then at least for others. Trust me though, you'll be glad later on that they're on seperate lines.

Edit: Technically, it doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely up to you. Both have the same meaning to the compiler.

I find it best to stick to an externally defined standard regardless of which code base I am working on. That way the styling standard is portable. In particular, I tend to use StyleCop to govern this, using the default rules as much as possible. In the default StyleCop ruleset, it is stated that the brace should be on the following line.

Answer (score 0):

You can write all the code in one line.. But I think it's more readable when you use the default method.. That's the only disadvantage.